# Robot Framework using Python, key press without selecting any button or element in the page

Tags: python-2.7, keypress, robotframework

I am automating one application using Robot Framework using Python. In a certain situation I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without selecting any button or element of the page once the page is loaded.

I have tried with the below example (using [`Press Key`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Key)), but it didn't work as I don't want to select any specific button or element of the page before press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the page.

Examples:

```
Press Key    text_field     q
Press Key    login_button   \\\13    # ASCII code for the Enter key
```

The below keyword is not recognized by the IDE, most probably because of version:

```
Press Key Native
```

Is there a solution to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the document root as the target of the "Press Key"?

Answer (score 5):

Linux Alternative can be [PyAutoGUI](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)

Although it works for Windows and MacOS(cross-platform) also, as described in the docs

PyAutoGUI works on Python 2 & 3. Install from PyPI with
`pip install pyautogui`

Examples:

```
import pyautogui

def send_keys():
    """
    Works on Windows/Mac/Linux
    """
    pyautogui.press('enter') #Presses enter
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'esc') #Performs ctrl+shift+esc
    pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!\n', interval=secs_between_keys)  #Useful for entering text, newline is Enter
    pyautogui.typewrite(['a', 'b', 'c', 'left', 'backspace', 'enter', 'f1'], interval=.4) #A list of key names can be passed too
```

Comment: great reference. thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to send a key press event to the page, but not at a specific element - target the `<body>` element in the page, using the `Press Key` keyword:

```
Press Key   xpath=//body        \ue00f    # this is the Page Down key
Press Key   css=body            \ue00e    # and this - Page Up
```

An up-to-date list of key codes can be found in selenium's source, the [webdriver.common.Keys module](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py) holds their definition.

---

IMHO libraries that execute keystrokes in the OS (like AutoIt, or Java's robot) should be avoided if possible - they make your automation scripts dependent on the execution machine (and operating system), and local only -  you can't run browsers tests against Selenium Hub (Sauce labs, Browsertstack, similar).

Answer (score 2):

Robot Framework Selenium library can only send keypresses to an element. If you want to send actual keypresses, you need to write your own library that does it. In Windows this can be done using SendKeys module.

Here is a library that defines "Send Enter Key" keyword for Robot Framework. I tested it quickly on Chrome, it might have problems with PhantomJS.

```
import SendKeys

def send_enter_key():
    """
    Sends ENTER key to application
    Works only in Windows
    """
    SendKeys.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Is there linux alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with two slashes, not three:

```
Press Key    text_field     q   
Press Key    login_button   \\13   # ASCII code for the Enter key
```

Comment: If you inject it as a variable, it is one slash. If you use it directly, it is two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the *[Press Keys](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys)* keyword:

- Press Keys \ ENTER
- Press Keys \ Example Write Words
- Press Keys \ TAB

and so on... I have Robot Framework 3.1.1 (Python 2.7.9 on win32) and [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html).

Comment: Unsure what the backslash indicates here, but I was able to use `xpath=//body` as in Todor's  answer.