# how to give ctrl+c command in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

In Robot Framework how do I give the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> command?

I have tried this line but it does not work

```
${crtl_c}    Evaluate    chr(int(3))    SSHLibrary.Write Bare    ${crtl_c}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  imagehorizon as a library :

```
Press Combination    KEY.CTRL    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PyAutoGUI](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html)

PyAutoGUI works on Windows/Mac/Linux on Python 2 & 3. Install from PyPI with
`pip install pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui

def CntrlC():
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') #Performs ctrl+c
```

Now just import the py file and use CntrlC as the Keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
${ctrl_c}    evaluate    chr(int(3))
SSHLibrary.Write Bare    ${crtl_c}
```

Or else you can give the line in variables section:

```
***variable***
${ctrl_c}    evaluate    chr(int(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working. The problem with the answers above is that you need an equal sign.

```
${ctrl-c}=                  evaluate      chr(int(3))
Write Bare                  ${ctrl-c}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refering to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28981076/6152737) on an SO question where if you're on windows, the SendKeys python library is used to send actual key presses to the system. In case you're on a linux based system it pretty much depends on the GUI you're using and a few other factors. This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714072/simulate-keystroke-in-linux-with-python) has some good content that might help you.

Comment: The problem is related with SSHLibrary. The solution may be by finding the right numeric value for the Ctrl-C combination. From the old days, I used to send (not on SSH) Ctrl-G (007) to make the terminal beep. If that works, you could try `Write Bare    "\\007"`