# I want to handle alert as in write `Username and Password` in it and then click OK

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

The popup comes when we navigate to website and asks for authentication.Something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78a8ict7uc4ybwr/Screenshot%202017-06-03%2023.59.37.png?dl=0). Please let me know how to handle the alert with username and pass, that pops up as this pop up could not be distinguished with firebug etc

I already tried "INPUT TEXT into prompt" `#input text into prompt  https://username:password@url.com`  but I get error that `There is no alert present`. However when I use function `Alert should be present` it gets passed

I am using robot framework and Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are running into is called BASIC web server authentication. While searching on SO there are a number of similar questions that have been asked over time. This [particular one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and-iedriver) is nice as it has several solution approaches that can be tried.

As the popup is technically not part of the page's DOM, this can not be addressed using xpath. There are roughly two approaches:

1. Fill in the text boxes using a key stroke simulator like [SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688170/robot-framework-using-python-key-press-without-selecting-any-button-or-element).
2. Prevent the popup from appearing.

In this case you're already on your way for the second one. By including the username and password in the url, the popup is prevented. The following Robot Script uses that example to access a local page that is secured by basic authentication using [this tutorial](http://prashanth-cpp.blogspot.nl/2009/05/setting-up-http-basic-authentication.html).

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test Chrome
    Create Webdriver    Chrome
    Go To    http://admin:admin@localhost:8090/basic-auth/
    Capture Page Screenshot    
    [Teardown]  Close All Browsers
```

As the popup is prevented, there is no need separately input the username and password.

Comment: I tried the same  `Create Webdriver    Chrome
    Go To    http://admin:admin@localhost:8090/basic-auth/` for the website I want to automate, but it did not do anything, as in, it opened the browser and took to the website but it did not type the username and password in the area. And as you can see in my question I was previously using the same approach but it did not work. @A.Kootstra  Although this approach works when I use normal selenium framework with Java or Python but not sure why it does not work with Robot Framework!

Comment: But are you logged into the application successfully? You would not see the pop-up at all with this approach. You'd directly go to the desired page/site and that is the proof of success.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I was using http previously though it works with https.

Comment: i have similar situation but with FTP , whenever i tried to pass the same like ftp://admin:admin@[IP of URL], it is not recognizing the username and password. No username and password is added to the ftp dialog. Any inputs here.

Comment: This is different from the original question and should be asked as a separate question.