# Image upload Popup issue with Robotframework.

Tags: javascript, python, popup, robotframework

I'm using Robot Framework, And I have an issue concerning uploading a file when a popup is displayed and I need to select a file to be uploaded.

When I click on upload a popup is displayed to select a file from the computer.
Did anyone try to handle this issue and how.

Please find the popup attached.

Thanks in Advance[image]

Comment: Use the `Choose File` keyword instead if you can. As that will directly upload the file instead of opening up the file browser. http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File

Comment: Isn't there another way? Because that doesn't work.
The Element where the path must be written is disabled, and is enabled only when the file is selected

Comment: Then you may have to use `AutoIt` but it's not the easiest thing in the world to set up

Comment: Yes, that's the last point I want to get into :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use keyboard key strokes to move through the file picking. On Windows the SendKeys module will allow you to do that. For more on this see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28981076/6152737).

Comment: Hi, so how do I add this to RobotFramework? 
Should I import the library?

Comment: The simplest way is indeed to save the example as a `name_of_library.py` and then add `Library    name_of_library.py` (assuming it's in the root of your project). Create the Python methods using the SendKeys module and  then call these functions as Keywords from Robot Framework.