# Robot Framework "Scroll Element Into View" not working when there is a fixed footer

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

I'm writing a UI automation using RobotFramework using SeleniumLibrary.

As seen in the image below there is a button hidden behind the fixed footer. I want to click that button using Robot Framework. I tried `Scroll Element Into View  <button_locator>` but it throws below exception.

`ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">...</a> is not clickable at point (1328, 656). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer-actions layout-align-end-center layout-row flex-1" flex="1" layout="row" layout-align="end center">...</div>`

Can someone please help me with this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you click the button manually?

Comment: @Todor Minakov, Yes I can. When the page is loaded this button is hidden behind the footer. I can manually scroll the page until this button is visible and then I can click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Press Key   xpath=//body        \ue00f    # this is the Page Down key
```

repeat 2x if neccesary
more info? here: [Robot Framework using Python, key press without selecting any button or element in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688170/robot-framework-using-python-key-press-without-selecting-any-button-or-element)